# What/Why is the upper voltage limit on step-up converter?

Tags: step-up

I bought one of these; they are sold all over the place:

[image]

The input voltage is listed as 3.6-6 V DC, and the output is at 20 kV. They require quite some current, and what I have laying around that provides that is a 8.4 V DC source.

**My question: what would happen if I used this source?**

Will the output voltage be higher? Will it just break / short? Will it work just fine but have a shorter expected life?

---

**EDIT**
This is a schematic I found for the device. (Nevermind the slightly different input voltage range). The element on the left is a transformer.
[image]

Comment: Hi, we have no idea what that black box is. You should at least post what kind of a circuit it is. If it is listed for max 6,6V and you feed 8,4V you should assume that it will get destroyed. It is never good practice to exceed the max specifications in any given device.

Comment: That looks like one of the cheap "1 million volt" generators you can find on e-Bay, Amazon, and Ali-Baba - every place that sells cheap crap to customers who don't know what to expect.

Comment: Expect it to go "bang, boom, smoke" if you feed it more than the "rated" voltage.  It might survive, it might not.  Also, be glad that the output is over rated.  If they could really put out the voltage they claim, the arcs between the output terminals could reach over 30 centimeters, easily - and they'd be deadly to be around 'cause they'd arc to you just as easily.

Comment: I've added a schematic that shows the components.

@JRE - I'm not sure I'm following your comment. 30 cm requires about 1 MV - this device only outputs 20 kV...

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  Since you didn't mention the voltage in the original question I assumed it was one of the typical "1 million volt" things that you can also buy all over the internet.

Comment: Ahh ok, got it. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

The outcome depends on how the device is implemented - you haven't provided a datasheet from which this could be deduced, but I doubt there is one. Using any device outside the absolute maximum ratings (this is an extra section in a complete datasheet), can have any effect. What is likely to happen is that it fails in a more or less catastrophic way.

I don't expect this thing to have any protection devices, so chances are that the internal step-up IC will emit magic smoke once. But there could also be an electrolytic capacitor which fails in a spectacular manner. After failure it could be that the input is shorted to the output or that it fails open, so no voltage is at the output.

If there is proper protection, it should fail in a safe manner, but even then it's probably not usable anymore without repair.

Of course there are also those devices which were carefully engineered and have high enough safety margins which will tolerate some abuse (without guarantee of course) and run fine even if used outside the specification for a long time.

But in the end, you never know and if you leave the specified range, all you do is completely your responsibility.